# How to have the same output of puri:uri-parsed-path using the alternative library in Common Lisp called Quri?

Tags: uri, common-lisp

Using the CL (SBCL) and the Puri library, I get on Slime's REPL:

```lisp
CL-USER> (puri:uri-parsed-path  (puri:parse-uri "http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html"))

(:ABSOLUTE "software" "emacs" "manual" "html_node" "emacs" "index.html")
```

I am trying to achieve the same output (a list with the split terms from the URL's path) using [**Quri**](https://github.com/fukamachi/quri) instead of Puri.

Unfortunately, I am not achieving it. I have tried `quri-parse-path`:

```lisp
CL-USER> quri-object
#<QURI.URI.HTTP:URI-HTTP http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/>
CL-USER> (quri:parse-path (quri:uri-path quri-object))
"/software/emacs/"
0
16
```

Does the library already support this operation?

I am not sure it does only by reading the Quri's documentation. I am still a noob in CL, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest getting the uri path, and splitting by "/":

```lisp
(quri:uri "http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html")
#<QURI.URI.HTTP:URI-HTTP http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html>

(quri:uri-path *)
"/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html"

(ql:quickload "str")
(str:split "/" * :omit-nulls t)
("software" "emacs" "manual" "html_node" "emacs" "index.html")
```